# PDFs rendered from a invoice definition hosting a hyperlink will not create a clickable link

Tags: acumatica

We have a requirement where we want to send an invoice that hosts a link that would direct a customer to pay the invoice being emailed to them via standard Acumatica Email delivery mechanism. When previewing the invoice we can click on the link without issue. However, the invoice that gets sent does not have a clickable link.

I Found this article on the subject which describes the same use case we are looking to achieve.
https://feedback.acumatica.com/ideas/ACU-I-1344
The discussion commentary points out that 2018 R2 has resolved this issue and I have indeed confirmed it works as expected on that release. We need to figure out what to do with the R1 version. Is there anything that can be done to get this link to work on 2018R1 and prior? 
I fear this may not be plausible and if so I may end up looking into getting the link into the email template itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acumatica versions prior to 2018R2 will not render the control as a PDF link object, it will render it as a standard text box.

As a workaround, you can exploit a behavior that most consumer friendly PDF client implements. They make any textbox whose text content is a valid URL a link control. Since it is still a text box control it doesn't apply the link font styling that PDF link control does by default.

Notice that while the font styling doesn't look like a link both Edge and Chrome PDF client make that text box clickable and act as a link because it's content (http://google.com) looks like a valid URL:
[image]

You can style the textbox to make it appear like a link:
[image]

The limitation of this approach is that the link description (text box Value property in report designer) must be in the form of a URL. It will work as a link in most general public consumer centric PDF client. Some PDF client geared towards professional printing might not implement this behavior but it's unlikely to be an issue for your client base.
[image]

For versions prior to 2018R2 there's no way to display a proper link control in PDF as it requires re-compilation of Acumatica report module with code for that feature. If you absolutely need it, you could open a support ticket to assess whether or not Acumatica could retro-fit that change as a hot-fix for previous versions but there's no guarantee it will happen.

Comment: This is very helpful HB_Acumatica, I will relay this workaround to the stakeholders. I have also noticed that this option will only work if the whole URL is on the same line. If the URL wraps within the text control we only get up to the point of the first wrap. I appreciate your help!

Comment: It's probably because the report designer flows the text with line break and carriage returns. To prevent wrapping behavior set properties Appearance->WrapText to False and Behavior Multiline to False. It will clip the URL display if too long but will prevent wrapping.